# How to find what direction the player is in from an enemy?

Tags: python, pyglet, game-ai

I have managed to get the enemy ai moving towards the player using this code (python and pyglet):

```
(dx, dy) = ((player.x - self.x)/math.sqrt((player.x - self.x) ** 2 + 
           (player.y - self.y) ** 2),(player.y - self.y)/math.sqrt((player.x - self.x)
           ** 2 + (player.y - self.y) ** 2))
newCoord = (self.x + dx * 3, self.y + dy * 3)
self.x,self.y = newCoord
```

However I am unsure of how to rotate the enemy sprite so they are facing the player. I am pretty sure that I could use some of the code above and rotate the player accordingly but I haven't been able to find a way that works.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, they are both really good :) I'm a bit stuck though, I'm getting results  like: 0.130292159729 for the angle but that can't be right can it? I can't see any rotation for the sprites :/

Comment: Maybe you need to convert the result to degree; `math.atan2(y,x) / math.pi * 180`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The information you have is 2 legs of a right triangle, and you are trying to find the angle. So

```
math.tan(angle) == float(player.y - self.y) / (player.x - self.x)
```

or

```
angle == math.atan(float(player.y - self.y) / (player.x - self.x))
```

But this atan will lose sign information, and dividing may give you `ZeroDivisionError`, which is exactly what [math.atan2](http://docs.python.org/library/math.html#math.atan2) is for:

```
angle = math.atan2(player.y - self.y, player.x - self.x)
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [`math.atan2()`](http://docs.python.org/library/math.html#math.atan2) with the delta y and x will give you the appropriate angle in radians.

```
>>> math.atan2(1, -1)
2.356194490192345
```